# What is the ? parameter for in these script and stylesheet references?

Tags: javascript, css

When looking at various web pages, I sometimes see statements like the following in the source.  These examples are taken from a few different sites.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js?v=1.5.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js?v=1.8.13"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/skin/core.js?ver=5212"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/skin/plugins.js?ver=5212"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/skin/mainpage.js?ver=5212"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?ver=5212" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css?v=04.23.2012.01" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stuff/lib/site.js?v=04.20.2012.00"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://css.nyt.com/css/0.1/screen/build/homepage/styles.css?v=20120119">
```

Can someone explain what these are for and what script is being used for it?  Is this so different versions of CSS/JS can be kept and sent based on the version number?

Comment: It's so that if the version changes, you automagically download a new version instead of possibly maintaining a cached version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for cache-busting; changing the parameter `?whatever` forces the browser to download the file again instead of fetching it from the cache.

Comment: I would imagine that it also serves as a form of "poor man's documentation," allowing you to see what version is actually in use on a given page.  Assuming, of course, that the backing script is maintained accordingly at the correct version; the version number parameter doesn't necessarily control the version being downloaded.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in some cases, sure, if you were to append the revision number as the parameter

Answer (score 1):

It's there so browsers that have cached a previous version of those files will request a new copy. By adding the version numbers or dates they are essentially creating a new name for the file thus bypassing caching.